# How to restart app using gulp when node modules updated?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-uglify

I am using npm link to link other package here in this project now when that package got updated i want to use auto watch feature and restart the app.

How to watch changes for node modules ?

gulp.js

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglifyes");
var gulpif = require("gulp-if");
var log = require("fancy-log");
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

    gulp.task("default", () => {
        return tsProject.src().pipe(tsProject()).pipe(gulpif(arg.env === 'prod', uglify())).pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
    });

    gulp.task('stream', ['default'], function develop() {
        var stream = nodemon({
            script: 'server.js',
            ext: 'js',
            watch: "../project/local",
            ignore: ['ignored.js'],
            tasks: ["default"]
        }) return stream.on('restart', function() {
            console.log('restarting nodemon')
        }).on('crash', function() {
            console.error('Application has crashed!\n') stream.emit('restart', 10)
        })
    })
```

Comment: You have it tagged. Have you read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) for it?

Comment: this is first time i am using gulp i read the documentation but didnt see anything related to node modules watch , can you please help ?

Comment: it should watch changes from this `watch: "../project/local"` directory